# JQuery Confirmation Dialog

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, confirmation

I have used the jQuery dialog code so that I can prompt my user. Is there a way to catch if the user clicks the close button (the 'X' in the top right? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shuold be able to just catch the beforeclose event ([docs to be found here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#event-beforeclose)).

Comment: Great, just the job, thanks.

Out of curiosity, why does this work:

beforeclose: function duffy(){MyFunctionToCancel()},

but not this:

beforeclose: MyFunctionToCancel(),

Thanks again.